# How can i make a proper Dio POST request?

Tags: xml, flutter, post, dio

I'm trying to use the Dio library to make a POST request to API.

```
    final authenticationRaw = '<GTSRequest command="version">'
      ' <Authorization account="XXXXXX" user="" password="XXXXX"/> '
      '</GTSRequest>';
  print(authenticationRaw);
//  final autRequest = XmlDocument.parse(authenticationRaw);
  print("help1");
  try {
    print("help2");
    Dio dio = Dio();

    print("helpcc");
    Response response = await dio.post(
      _baseUrl,
      data: authenticationRaw,
      options: Options(method: 'POST'),
    );

    print("help3");
```

i never get to print help3.

can someone help?

thanks

Comment: add catchError to find what is the problem. `Response response = await dio.post(
      _baseUrl,
      data: authenticationRaw,
      options: Options(method: 'POST'),
    ).catchError((e)=> print(e));`

Comment: Thanks Reza. I'm getting a http 301 error although  using Postman everything works just fine!

Comment: Could you show the API response? 301 means your request moved permanently. The new permanent URI should be given by the `Location` field in the response. Sometimes server process HTTP and HTTPS request separately. Check your URL carefully